# what happens if, in redis.conf, you set the dbfilename to null, and the dir to /dev

Tags: redis

Basically, we want to not only ensure that redis doesn't generate snapshots, we want to ensure that if it finds one, it ignores it.  We've commented out the "save" lines, and set appendonly to no.  But we still had it start up with a stale rdb file that got left behind.  We want to be absolutely sure that can't happen (even if some random event causes an rdb file to appear).

One thought I had, make redis write to/ read from /dev/null.  Set dir to /dev, and set the filename to null.

But I'm curious about the side effects:
1) if it tries to write a snapshot to /dev/null, what happens?
2) if it tries to read /dev/null as if it's a rdb file, what happens?

For #1 I expect it will write it all out and then close and not care. (assuming we still had save values set -- since we don't, it shouldn't bother trying)

For #2 ... I expect it will read a zero length file, and gracefully move on exactly like it didn't read any file at all.

But will it expect certain key fingerprints and complain?  Will it retry reading the file N times before moving on (creating start-up latency)?  Will it realize it didn't get any data from a file, and think it should have, and then exit?

Before we try, we want to know what to expect :-)

Comment: Well, just try it?